# touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled not worked

Tags: unity, unityscript

i m tired to handle and solve issues related to multitouch. i m use maximume 5 touch simultaneously but when two touches are down on two object and i moved my fingures then that both touches fired TouchPhase.Ended event but not fired TouchedPhase.Canceled.

I want to fired TouchPhase.Canceled when i my fingures out of those objects.

```
if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) { hitObject.GetComponent ().TouchDown (hitObject); }

if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) { hitObject.GetComponent ().TouchExit (hitObject); }

if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) { hitObject.GetComponent ().TouchStay (hitObject); }

if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) { print ("Touched canceled...."); hitObject.GetComponent ().TouchExit (hitObject); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally "touchphase.cancelled" occurs when the user puts more than the maximum number of touches the system can track on the screen. So, it does not get fired as you get fingers off.